# Calling an async function from a sync function

Tags: async-await, blazor, blazor-client-side, matblazor

I am building a Blazor client side application. I am using [MatBlazor](https://www.matblazor.com/) components.

I have two MatSelectString controls on a page. The first one is used to select a category, and the second one to select products from the category. So I have it setu up like so:

```
<MatSelect Outlined="true" Label="Category" @bind-Value="@Category">
    <MatOptionString></MatOptionString>
    @foreach (var cat in GetCategories())
    {
        <MatOptionString Value="@cat">@cat</MatOptionString>
    }
</MatSelect>
<MatSelect Outlined="true" Disabled="@(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Category))" Label="Product" @bind-Value="@Product" >
    <MatOptionString></MatOptionString>
    @foreach (var prod in GetProducts(Category))
    {
        <MatOptionString Value="@prod">@prod</MatOptionString>
    }
</MatSelect>
```

Within the `GetProducts(Category)` code, I want to call the backend. The issue is that there is only a `HttpClient.GetJsonAsync<>()` method, that cannot be called from within a non-async method. But GetProduct() cannot be made async.

Things I have tried:

- Putting the call to my function inside an async lambda (not allowed in foreach or in other code blocks)
- Using Task.Result (it hangs)
- Putting the back-end call in other component level async events (gets called multiple times)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ValueChanged` EventCallback:

```
<MatSelect 
    Outlined="true" 
    Label="Category" 
    ValueChanged="(string i)=>OnChangeCategory(i)"> @* <-- here *@
    <MatOptionString></MatOptionString>
    @foreach (var cat in GetCategories())
    {
        <MatOptionString Value="@cat">@cat</MatOptionString>
    }
</MatSelect>

@code
{
   protected async Task OnChangeCategory(string newValue)
   {
      this.Category = newValue;
      // call backend async tasks
      // ...
   }
```

Check it out at [blazorfiddle.com](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/p3qsjmh6)

Comment: Extra points for the elegant casting of the integer to a string inline using: "(string i)=>" 

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWashington appreciate  Most Matblazor controls are generic, without explicit type on anonymous function it is unable to inferring type.

Comment: @daniherrera It would be great if you submitted a PR on MatBlazor for an example of this.

Comment: @daniherrera I am trying your code in a WebAssembly project and I am receiving this error "Unhandled exception rendering component: MatBlazor.MatSelect`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]] requires a value for the 'ValueExpression' parameter. Normally this is provided automatically when using 'bind-Value'.". Any idea why it requires also a ValueExpression parameter ?

Comment: Here it is my code 

`<MatSelect Label="@strings.Authority" ValueChanged="(Int64? nv)=>OnChangeAuthority(nv)" >
                    @if (Authorities != null)
                        @foreach (var au in Authorities)
                        {
                            <MatOption TValue="Int64?" Value="@au.Id">@au.Name</MatOption>
                        }
                </MatSelect>`